# White and reddish marks on the final rendered image

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I made a render but somehow there are these weird white and reddish marks, which I don't think is noise, on the final rendered image

[image: Here is the image the marks are just below the lid on the right]

Marks are just below the lid on the right

https://pasteall.org/blend/6c022b3cae91473f99e54d4be8ad3dc4

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/6c022b3cae91473f99e54d4be8ad3dc4

Comment: I'm not sure what that is because my render's don't have these artifacts. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPdo3.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I think maybe there is something wrong with my blender because your render came out fine, somehow.

Comment: I tried it as well and yes it came out without any white/red marks, the only thing that I noticed that your cup has inverted faces but that shouldn't cause this issue

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.